# UploadfileHandler.php blue imp file upload i want to set paths with variables and it seem to not work at all

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload, blueimp, jquery-upload-file-plugin

I want to connect this to my database and change path ways with variable already set with a name.

mysql_connect.php completely works with my other home page of websites, it holds a variable: `$path_way` inside and it wont work as a path on this UploadfileHandler.php.

I done a lot of research on the web I cant seem to find a clear answer or any correct solution.

Please note this is only a small part of the code that's only being edited.

```
require('mysql_connect.php');
function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
    $this->options = array(
        'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/',
        'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/../../../uploads/user/table1/'.$path_way.'/',
        'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/../../../uploads/user/table1/'.$path_way.'/',
        'user_dirs' => false,
        'mkdir_mode' => 0755,
        'param_name' => 'files',
        // Set the following option to 'POST', if your server does not support
        // DELETE requests. This is a parameter sent to the client:
        'delete_type' => 'DELETE',
        'access_control_allow_origin' => '*',
        'access_control_allow_credentials' => false,
        'access_control_allow_methods' => array(
            'OPTIONS',
            'HEAD',
            'GET',
            'POST',
            'PUT',
            'PATCH',
            'DELETE'
        ),
```

Comment: please someone help if any ideas in bypassing this if no correct way to use the variable would be greatly appreciated